# Invalid syntax in if/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

The code is written partly in the Dutch language (my native language). The error is in the line with the `else` function. When I run the script the error "invalid syntax" appears and the colon is highlighted as cause of the error.

How to fix this?

```
    print("welke kleur ben jij?")

    Kr = 0
    Kg = 0
    Kb = 0
    Kg = 0

    print("vraag 1: \n Als je een auto zou kopen welke auto word het dan?
     \n A, een Lamborghini \n B, een Ferrari \n C, een Jaguar \n D, een lada                          
    natuurlijk! ")
    if input("a"):
Kg + 1

    elif input("b"):
Kr + 1

    else: input("c"):
Kb + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Python has significant whitespace; indentation denotes blocks of code as opposed to `{...}` in some other languages.

Try indenting the code that directly follows the `if`, `elif` and `else` statements, e.g.:

```
    if input("a"):
        Kg + 1

    elif input("b"):
        Kr + 1

    elif input("c"):
        Kb + 1
```

Note also that `else` should not have a condition associated with it. It is executed only in the event that `if` and `elif` statements are not executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need `elif's` and also `+=`:

```
    Kg + 1 # should be `+=` which is the same as doing kg = kg + 1
```

`Kg + 1` etc.. actually does nothing

I would also use the following logic, `if input("a")` etc.. again does not really do what you think:

```
inp = input() # get the input

if inp == "a": # check the input value
    Kg += 1
elif inp == "b":
   Kr += 1    
elif inp == "c":
    Kb += 1
```

You would probably want in all in a `while loop`:

```
print("welke kleur ben jij?")

Kr = 0
Kg = 0
Kb = 0
Kg = 0

print("vraag 1: \n Als je een auto zou kopen welke auto word het dan?\n A, een Lamborghini \n B, een Ferrari \n C, een Jaguar \n D, een lada natuurlijk! ")

while True:
    inp = input("Please choose a, b or c")
    if inp == "a":
        Kg += 1  
        break    # break out of the loop
    elif input("b"):
       Kr += 1
       break
    elif input("c"):
        Kb += 1
        break
    else:  # user did not input any correct value
        print("Invalid input, try again")
```

It is just an example of how to take input from a user until the input is valid, you would have to decide what the best way to break the loop  etc.. .